# When conda install django, PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, permissions, anaconda

When I run `conda install django`, I get the following error:

> Solving environment: done
>
> ==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
>
> current version: 4.4.10
>
> latest version: 4.4.11
>
> Please update conda by running
>
> ```
> $ conda update -n base conda
> ```
>
> ## Package Plan ##
>
> environment location: /opt/anaconda/anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs: 
>       - django
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> ```
> django: 2.0.2-py36hd476221_0
> ```
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Preparing transaction: done
>
> Verifying transaction: done
>
> Executing transaction: failed
>
> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error
>   occurred while installing package
>   'defaults::django-2.0.2-py36hd476221_0'. PermissionError(13,
>   'Permission denied') Attempting to roll back.
>
> Rolling back transaction: done
>
> PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed.

I changed the permission of /opt/anaconda/anaconda3 recursively.

Comment: You should install anaconda3 in HOME directory, e.g. `~/.anaconda3`.

If you install it in a directory owned by root then you will have these permission errors.

Comment: Can you explain what this means and how this can be done?

Answer (score 11):

I solved with:

```
sudo chown -R user anaconda3
```

where `user` is your username and `anaconda3` is the path to your anaconda installation, which can be found by running `conda info`.

I used [this issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3448) as reference.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add that the same goes for windows command prompt. You must run the Anaconda prompt as Admin.

Comment: I don't think you should have to. What directory did you install anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

Permission Denied.. That's likely because you are not running your command as root. Try and run your command as superAdmin

Comment: This worked for me, but I've heard before that you should never have to run `sudo conda install ...` anything because conda should have the correct rights or something. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Sudo means super user do... So its more like your environment won't allow you install condo ... But you are telling it you are a super user .. Hence it should install condo.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem.
For Windows:
Try deleting the pip folders in AppData/Temp. Python is unable to delete these folders and create new pip folders for unpacking the new installations.