# I'm trying to update conda and get PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I would like to update conda, anaconda, and python to the latest versions. I executed the following commands and received the following prompts. What's happening and how can I fix this? I appreciate the help

```
C:\Users\nabr>conda update --all
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.4.10
  latest version: 4.5.11

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



# All requested packages already installed.


C:\Users\nabr>conda update -n base conda
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda: 4.4.10-py36_0 --> 4.5.11-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.4.10-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

Comment: May be you need to run this as an administrator?

Comment: You should not run conda as administrator, it can be troublesome. Instead you should allow write permission to your user account on the whole conda environment. Likely `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I found some solutions to this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092807/when-conda-install-django-permissionerror13-permission-denied).

The solutions included:

1. running the Anaconda prompt as administrator and reinstalling Anaconda, then changing from 'for all users' to 'for myself' "
2. deleting the pip folders in AppData/Temp
3. installing python packages, dependencies or updates as "sudo chown -R user anaconda3", where "user" is your username and "anaconda3" is the path to your anaconda installation. The path to the anaconda installation can be found by running "conda info". This was the most popular solution on that post, and was based in this other post [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3448).

I did not try solution 1, but they said that it would work if you have installed Anaconda in a directory owned by root, what is the cause of the permission error.
I did try solution 2 then 3, though. Solution 2 did not work for me, while solution 3 required the installation of BASH on Windows.

The problem with solution 3 for me was that the term "sudo" was not recognized as an internal or external command because I was trying to run a Unix command on Windows System. More information about this matter [here](https://code2care.org/howto/sudo-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command). For instance, "sudo" means you are telling Anaconda you are a Super User, or a Super Admin.

So I would need to install BASH to use the Linux command line in Windows. More information on how to install BASH on Windows 10 [here](https://How%20to%20Install%20Bash%20on%20Windows%2010).

In the end I just used "pip install 'somepackages' to install the packages I needed, which is a solution that is not going to help you, as you are trying to updated 'conda'.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and solved.

Run Anaconda Prompt as administrator.

Comment: "Solving" something by running it as administractor is generally a bad idea, especially on windows