# ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::icu-58.2-ha925a31_3'

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, chatbot, recurrent-neural-network

I created environment using anaconda prompt `conda create -n talkingbot python=3.5` then install `pip install tensorflow==1.0.0` (followed same command as used in one udemy course) but when I tried to install spyder
using `conda install spyder` then it gives me this error :

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::icu-58.2-ha925a31_3'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\anaconda3\\envs\\talkingbot\\Library\\bin\\icudt58.dll'
()
```

then I tried to install spyder using anaconda navigator but from there also spyder was not installed.

Help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too when i creating a new environment with **python == 3.9**, then something weird occurs and I can't use this environment anymore, and I can't reinstall packages there, it gives

"ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698):"

when I create a new env with python == 3.7.9 all goes smoothly for now

P.S.1 i followed this answer, it helped to overcome '698' error https://stackoverflow.com/a/57693590/9153119

P.S.2 Hmm... looks like "ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698):" was caused by my Antivirus protection "Malwarebytes", i turned it off, and all goes smoothly with any new installations.

Answer (score -2):

you must execute this command:
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab

And after execute
conda install notebook ipykernel